# Do we need to test private functions on CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, testing, code-coverage, cakephp-2.0, xdebug

I thought private functions should never be tested and only the public interfaces should be.

But then, using XDebug to see the coverage of my function i find out that it decreases as it takes into account the private functions.

What do you think about it?
THanks.

Comment: no I don't think you can (well, with quite some effort maybe) or should test them. same with protected. maybe there is some setting for xdebug to ignore private ones?

Comment: I have no idea bout Xdebug settings. But thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you test private functions? Everything should be tested.

Comment: That was what i learned, you can find it all over the net: http://lassekoskela.com/thoughts/24/test-everything-but-not-private-methods/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a believe that you should test all of your methods, private and protected included. They have logic within them that needs to be tested, despite their visibility to other classes. In order to test protected methods, you often need to create a proxy class that makes the methods public.

```
class MyClass {

   protected function protected_method() {
     // do stuff
   }

}
```

In the test case, you would create another class and make its protected methods public, like so

```
class TestMyClass extends MyClass {

   public function protected_method() {
     return parent::protected_method();
   }

}
```

Now you can test `TestMyClass::protected_method()` within the test case.

This is not the only way to do it. The creator of PHPUnit, Sebastian Bergmann, wrote a blog post about it here: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html

Comment: Note that that's an E_STRICT error, if desired you can instead use [reflections](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to just make the protected method public - though personally this is the point to consider if the method _should_ be protected or if the code should be refactored so the equivalent logic is public. I do tests _some_ protected methods - typically fundamental building blocks I want to be absolutely sure work as intended.

Comment: Unfortunately sebastian's blog post is offline now :( I'd love to know what he had to say about all this - I tend to code in a functional style and I don't think it's unreasonable to want to test every single method I write with edge-cases.

Comment: @mils I dug it up on the internet archive for you. enjoy! https://web.archive.org/web/20120418125512/http://sebastian-bergmann.de:80/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your private / protected methods are run as part of your tests, but don't test them directly. If a private method exists, it must be called by a public method somewhere. So, call that public method in a way that in turn calls the private methods.

One of the cool things about testing is being able to do a massive re-factor on your code, without having to change the tests. Your tests sit as an anchor to tell you when it's all working again. If you test your private methods then your tests end up becoming tightly coupled to your code and it makes big refactors like that a pain, cos you have to change tests and code at the same time.